# AWS EC2 / MySql - spring boot Unable to determine jdbc url from datasource

Tags: java, mysql, amazon-web-services, spring-boot

I have a simple Spring Boot application that I'm trying to deploy on an Amazon EC2 instance based on the Amazon AMI. It uses a MySql database (version 8.0.15).

I've created the database on AWS, and when I point the configuration at it from my local system, it works. I'm also able to access it from MySql Workbench.

But when I upload the Spring Boot jar file to the EC2 instance and run it, it's unable to connect to the database, with the  message "Unable to determine jdbc url from datasource":

```
2019-05-31 20:51:38.266  WARN 5150 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.orm.jpa.DatabaseLookup           : Unable to determine jdbc url from datasource

org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Could not get Connection for extracting meta-data; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Failed to obtain JDBC Connection; nested exception is com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
```

Here are the relevant entries from the configuration:

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://mydbinstance.xxxxxxxx.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com:3306/todo_db
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=mypassword
```

The java version on the server is

```
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_201-b09)
```

On my local system, the java version is

```
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-b16)
```

Here are the contents of pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> 
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.todoapp.com.webservices</groupId>
    <artifactId>restful-web-services</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>restful-web-services</name>
    <description>Todo restful App built in Spring Boot</description>


    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

    <dependency>

            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Here's a more complete stack trace. The error about not being able to read the URL comes at the end.

```
2019-06-01 02:04:25.434  INFO 14791 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2019-06-01 02:04:26.696 ERROR 14791 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.

com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:174) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.13.jar!/:8.0.13]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:64) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.13.jar!/:8.0.13]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:835) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.13.jar!/:8.0.13]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:455) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.13.jar!/:8.0.13]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:240) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.13.jar!/:8.0.13]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:207) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.13.jar!/:8.0.13]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:136) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:369) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:198) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:467) [HikariCP-3.2.0.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:541) [HikariCP-3.2.0.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115) [HikariCP-3.2.0.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) [HikariCP-3.2.0.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.fetchConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:151) [spring-jdbc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:115) [spring-jdbc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:78) [spring-jdbc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:319) [spring-jdbc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:356) [spring-jdbc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DatabaseLookup.getDatabase(DatabaseLookup.java:73) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaProperties.determineDatabase(JpaProperties.java:142) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration.jpaVendorAdapter(JpaBaseConfiguration.java:112) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f5c20854.CGLIB$jpaVendorAdapter$5(<generated>) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f5c20854$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$81884254.invoke(<generated>) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244) [spring-core-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:363) [spring-context-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f5c20854.jpaVendorAdapter(<generated>) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) [spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:622) [spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:456) [spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1288) [spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1127) [spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:538) [spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498) [spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) [spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) [spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) [spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:273) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1237) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1164) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:857) [spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:760) [spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:509) [spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1288) [spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1127) [spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:538) [spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498) [spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) [spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) [spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) [spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:273) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1237) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1164) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:857) [spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:760) [spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:509) [spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1288) [spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1127) [spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:538) [spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498) [spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) [spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) [spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) [spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1083) ~[spring-context-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:853) ~[spring-context-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546) ~[spring-context-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142) ~[spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) ~[spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) ~[spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) ~[spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) ~[spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at com.todoapp.com.webservices.restfulwebservices.RestfulWebServicesApplication.main(RestfulWebServicesApplication.java:10) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48) ~[restful-web-services-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87) ~[restful-web-services-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50) ~[restful-web-services-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51) ~[restful-web-services-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:61) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.13.jar!/:8.0.13]
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:105) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.13.jar!/:8.0.13]
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:151) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.13.jar!/:8.0.13]
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createCommunicationsException(ExceptionFactory.java:167) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.13.jar!/:8.0.13]
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:91) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.13.jar!/:8.0.13]
    at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.connect(NativeSession.java:152) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.13.jar!/:8.0.13]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:955) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.13.jar!/:8.0.13]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:825) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.13.jar!/:8.0.13]
    ... 84 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:155) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.13.jar!/:8.0.13]
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:65) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.13.jar!/:8.0.13]
    ... 87 common frames omitted

2019-06-01 02:04:26.701  WARN 14791 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.orm.jpa.DatabaseLookup           : Unable to determine jdbc url from datasource

org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Could not get Connection for extracting meta-data; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Failed to obtain JDBC Connection; nested exception is com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked security group where your DB is associated? Or security group of your web server? Check whether they're in the same VPC, and that the security group allows connection in port 3306 between each other.

Comment: Yes, that was exactly the problem. It seems like somehow, there should have been something to provide a more helpful error message - I spend a full day on this thing. Thanks so much!